# jQuery Datepicker .val() is blank however a date is displayed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is my first question.

I have looked for an answer but my searches seem to bring back a lot of ways to enforce the datepicker value is empty, or being able to access the selected value which is not an option here.

### Background to the problem

I have a table with a dynamic amount of rows, each row contains a few datepickers (we'll call them A datepicker, B datepicker, C datepicker). It also contains a child row that is hidden until the 'Expand for more details' button is clicked, at which point there are a few more fields appearing. One of those fields is a 'Comments' field.

The requirement I have is that when the A datepicker is changed that a 'Comment' MUST be required to go along with that. I am able to tell when the datepicker is changed and therefore to send a message via the validator of the 'Comments' telling the user that it is now required.

## The requirement

When entering details into the comments section, I need to be able to check if there is a date selected in the A datepicker so that we can dynamically warn the user that the comments section needs to be X many characters IF there is a date in the A datepicker.

## The problem

It appears that when the jQuery datepicker is changed that the .value is not updated. When the row is populated it is possible that the A datepicker can be empty, not all fields require that particular date to be set and therefore not all 'Comment' fields need to be set either.

So I can tell when the datepicker is changed and get the 'Comments' field to be required. However a user can then fill out the 'Comments' field with a blank entry or enter a value that doesn't meet the X amount of characters limit. This behaviour is OK for when there is not a date selected. So when a date is selected I need to enforce the rule.

My problem is that I can't tell if a date is selected or not!

In the example below I had a blank datepicker, I then chose a date and opened developer tools. In the overview of the web page we can see that the date is set to 20th Jan 2018.

[Overview of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQNHR.jpg)

however through the developer tools we can see that the value is actually empty.

[Datepicker value is set to ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLicp.jpg)

This behaviour is also true when the datepicker was not initially blank, rather than the value being the new date it still retains the old date. In the example below I changed the date from the 23rd of December 2017 to the 31st of December 2017.

[Pre-Populated datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJt3.jpg)

And in developer tools the value is still set to the previous value.

[Changed to new date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRxqb.jpg)

## Technicalities

I am using MVC and jQuery, I am not looking for a solution that involves having to go back to the controller as that usually requires the user having to press a submit button and my requirement is that it needs to be able to respond upon selecting the date and entering comments. I'd just like a way to be able to get the displayed date from the datepicker and not it's previous value.

This matters because if it's going from previously having a date into now a blank date, it affects the requirement so that comments are no longer required as there isn't a date. Vice versa if going from a blank date to a selected date.

### Things I have tried

I am trying to write this into the OnChange method of 'Comments', so that I can check if there is a date selected or not.

I have tried directly calling it in my .js file with the below. For option 4 and 5 it's contained in a .each loop that goes through ALL the rows in my table and finds the row relating to the 'Comments' field that was changed.

(Please note that parentRow refers to the selected table row which contains the dates (the row that contains the comments field is the child row)).

```html
1) var dateValue = $(parentRow).find("input[name$='datepicker_A']").datepicker("getDate");

2) var dateValue = $(parentRow).find("input[name$='datepicker_A']").val();

3) var datepicker_A = document.getElementById('datepicker_A');

var dateValue = datepicker_A.val();

4) var dateValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("d/M/y", $(this).find("input[name$='datepicker_A']").val());

5) var dateValue = $(this).find("input[name$='datepicker_A']").val();
```

All of the above return the previous value of the datepicker and not the newly selected one. So my question is.. how do I get it to recognise the new value?

### TL:DR

jQuery datepicker doesn't seem to change the .val() property of the input field when selecting a new date, instead the .val() is always the previous value. How can I access the new value via javascript/jQuery?

Comment: I think those down voting should also provide comments.

Comment: @HarshWardhan I agree!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
<div>
   Select date: <input id="thedate" type="text" class="date-pick" />
</div>
```

And your JavaScript (I am using jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery UI 1.9.2 here too)

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText); // Put your code in here
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5kemyga/2/)

Comment: Hi, if I have understood this correctly this will fire the code when you select a date viajQuery date-picker? If that is the case then my question has been misunderstood, I need to get the date from the datepicker when the comment textbox is changed.